# Multiple buttons inside loop doesn't hide and show with .hide() in windows form c# application

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I'm trying to cover the image with buttons like this :

[image: image1]

Underneath that there's an arrow section like this :

[image: image2]

I have a for loop and I'm trying to hide and show buttons with buttonx.hide() and buttonx.show() function.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

    if (i % 3 == 0) {
      button2.Hide();
      button3.Show();
      button4.Show();
      button2.Refresh();
      button3.Refresh();
      button4.Refresh();
    } else if (i % 3 == 1) {
      button2.Show();
      button3.Hide();
      button4.Show();
      button2.Refresh();
      button3.Refresh();
      button4.Refresh();

    } else if (i % 3 == 2) {
      button2.Show();
      button3.Show();
      button4.Hide();
      button2.Refresh();
      button3.Refresh();
      button4.Refresh();

    }

    clientMessage(i);

  }
```

But the form freezes and the buttons don't go invisible (hiden). but the program works and gives output.

- I tried putting this hiding function in the client message function it doesn't work.
- I tried putting refresh for all buttons in form1_load it doesn't work.
- I tried using buttonx.visible = false; it doesn't work.
- I tried using label and imagebox as a cover it doesn't work

Inside the clientMessage function, there's an TCP/Ip connection and the picturebox function works. here's what the client-side looks like :

```
void clientMessage(int i) {

   try {

     TcpClient client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 1071);
     string message = "Portakal";

     pictureBox2.Image = ConniesClient.Properties.Resources.redButton;
     pictureBox2.Refresh();
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
     Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
     NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

     stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

     Debug.WriteLine("Sent from client : " + message);

     data = new byte[256];

     String responseData = String.Empty;
     Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
     responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
     Debug.WriteLine("Received at client : " + responseData);

     pictureBox3.Image = ConniesClient.Properties.Resources.redButton;
     pictureBox3.Refresh();

     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);

     stream.Close();
     client.Close();

   } catch (ArgumentNullException e) {
     Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException: {0}", e);
   } catch (SocketException e) {
     Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
   }

 }
```

Comment: I suppose that this code is inside some kind of event handler. In that case you should consider that the updates to the buttons visibility are executed only when your code exits from the event handler. While looping it just accumulates the commands for the form engine without changing anything on the UI

Comment: Should I need to add the clientMessage() code also?

Comment: It seems you need to learn quite a lot in order to achieve what you want. You can't mix user interface code and communications like that at all. The TCP might perhaps work somehow on its own, but needs a good rewrite to work well in an application with a user interface. I recommend a book, preferably based on WPF rather than the outdated WinForms technology. Also use async, and no Thread.Sleep.

Comment: Yeah C# is not my strongest suit but thanks I'll look into those topics but rn I have a deadline tomorrow and the only part remain is the button hiding. I realized the refresh() doesn't work as I intended and it refreshes the visibility of the button at the end of the loop.

Comment: Because that's when you exit the event handler that this for-loop likely resides in, as @Steve mentioned. The moment you exit the event handler, all the user interface updates happens instantly, so all you see is the ending state. As long as you're inside the event handler, your user interface remains frozen. The way out of this is to learn how to program user interfaces, which involves using events, timers, async, tasks, etc. Try to stay away from old fashioned threads. Sorry, but I don't know how to fix this in a short time.

Answer (score 0):

As @Bent Tranberg and @Steve mentioned in the comments the problem is caused by threads so here's the little come around about this problem it's probably not the best way to do it but it's working :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++)
    {

        if (i % 3 == 0)
        {
            pictureBox9.Hide();
            pictureBox9.Refresh();
            pictureBox10.Show();
            pictureBox10.Refresh();
            pictureBox11.Show();
            pictureBox11.Refresh();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        else if (i % 3 == 1)
        {

            pictureBox9.Show();
            pictureBox9.Refresh();
            pictureBox10.Hide();
            pictureBox10.Refresh();
            pictureBox11.Show();
            pictureBox11.Refresh();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);

        }
        else if (i % 3 == 2)
        {
            pictureBox9.Show();
            pictureBox9.Refresh();
            pictureBox10.Show();
            pictureBox10.Refresh();
            pictureBox11.Hide();
            pictureBox11.Refresh();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
     

        clientMessage();
    }
}
```

As I mentioned PictureBox was working so I used 3 separate PictureBox and hide them.

Comment: Rather than using `Thread.Sleep`, make the handler `async void` and use `await Task.Delay`. Sleeping in a UI app (even for 100 ms) is bad form